# CSS Fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css

The following HTML creates a simple layout with a fixed sidebar, but I want to put the sidebar on the right-hand side of the content

Please see the code snippet:

```css
#container
    {
     width: 1140px;
     max-width: 98%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     position: relative;
     min-height: 100%;
    }
    #header
    {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 20;
     width: 180px;
     padding-top: 100px;
     text-align: right;
    }
    #maincontent
    {
     padding-left: 220px;
     padding-top: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" />
     </head>
     <body>
     
      <div id="container">
      
       <header id="header">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       </header>
       
       <div id="maincontent">
        <div style="height:1280px;background:#333;"></div>
       </div>
      
       <div style="height:100px;"></div>
      
      </div>
     
     </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that I would need to specify the `right` on the sidebar (#header) and in doing so would mean the sidebar WOULD NO LONGER honour the container...

Any ideas how I could get around this? Thanks

Comment: Use the id of the div instead of saying 'sidebar' and you'll get more help.

Comment: Once you've solved this, do Google about why one shouldn't use IDs in CSS. :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick to this that I just found is to position the item that you want to show up on the right side (header) how you want it to show up. So float it over there.

Then add an inner container that is fixed.

Full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jupitercow/MjPC4/

So, I updated your header CSS like this:

```
#header
{
    float: right;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}
#header .inner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 180px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? See http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/fDxdj/.

Tip: rename header to sidebar... ;)

But I don't understand what you mean by

> doing so would mean the sidebar WOULD NO LONGER honour the container

since `position: fixed` doesn't honour anything. Not in your current sample, not never. It only honours the browser window, like it's supposed to.

Comment: if you don't use the `top, left, right or bottom` attributes then the fixed element will position itself inside the container instead of the browser window. In your example by using `right:0` you have made it stick to the side of the browser window instead of the container

Comment: Yeh as you're telling the element to be fixed but not fixed in any point so it just stays where it is. BUT I need to move to the right but not use any of the postion values otherwise I get that issue

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
  float:right;
}
```

Remove those huge paddings from #maincontent and if necessary fix #maincontent width.

Comment: That would NOT make the header fixed though