# How to make a static sidebar, which doesn't move when page is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a website that has the following layout:
[image: Website layout]

I want to make the sidebar (F/T container) a social network link. I want that div to be sticking to the right side, even if the viewer scrolls down the page, so that he/she can access Facebook/Twitter all the time. How can I achieve this with pure CSS(external sheet of course) and HTML (no Javascript). I am particularly asking which div should I put the sidebar in. Then, I guess I should use a `position:static` property in CSS.

If Javascript is required, could somebody send me a link to an already made function (I don't know how to work with this language)?
Here's my HTML code by now (I think I can handle the CSS part):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style></style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="nav">

            </div>
        </header>        
        <div id="intro">
        </div>
        <div id="content">//important content here (visible only when scrolled down)        
        </div>

        <div id="footer"></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

There is already a similar problem but only with one div-I have two.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Fixed sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456750/css-fixed-sidebar)

Comment: Have a look for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/jupitercow/MjPC4/

Comment: I forgot to write it: the div with id="intro" is the part of the page, visible on loading.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please add code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar The problem is similar in estetics, but I have two divs one under the other and a sidebar, while the given example has only one div and a sidebar on the right.

Comment: Don't let yourself being deceived by the keyword `static`. It's `fixed` what you're looking for. Every element is positioned `static`, unless defined otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjmwWy?editors=1100#0

**HTML**

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .page-contents {
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    .social-actions {
      background: #777;
      color: #000;
      width: 150px;
      height:70px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 100px;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="page-contents">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a nisi enim. Cras eu aliquet ante. Duis et urna efficitur,
          condimentum urna auctor, interdum arcu. Sed in enim eu enim congue vehicula. Aenean eget ligula eu mi vehicula suscipit
          vel vitae mi. Integer a nisl feugiat, faucibus lectus sed, elementum orci. Nullam quam magna, euismod at lorem a, gravida
          imperdiet dui. Vestibulum id tellus lorem.</p>

        <p>Vestibulum orci tortor, malesuada sit amet hendrerit vel, maximus vitae elit. Quisque sed dapibus arcu. Quisque eget
          venenatis libero, sit amet interdum turpis. Mauris risus odio, scelerisque eu molestie in, venenatis vel ante. Proin
          et diam leo. Curabitur gravida, turpis a consectetur porta, ipsum nibh lobortis arcu, non maximus justo nibh vel sem.
          Cras faucibus, quam quis tempor interdum, elit lacus dapibus nisi, eleifend pretium lacus lorem sit amet libero. Ut
          interdum neque nisi, a scelerisque purus porttitor eget. Nulla pretium aliquam commodo. Interdum et malesuada fames
          ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla mattis id arcu ut porta.</p>

        <p>Maecenas vitae mi consequat, scelerisque massa interdum, posuere tortor. Nam blandit ultricies nisl, viverra tincidunt
          lectus semper ac. Phasellus porta augue tortor, vel venenatis sapien aliquet congue. Sed luctus consequat arcu at venenatis.
          Morbi accumsan ligula ultricies elit vulputate, et molestie sem interdum. Etiam congue aliquam augue, eu efficitur
          felis. Vestibulum pellentesque tellus tellus, at venenatis ligula finibus id. Quisque id accumsan nibh.</p>

        <p>In at purus erat. Etiam vitae purus vel orci ultrices congue. Aliquam porta at lectus ultrices volutpat. Vivamus scelerisque
          vel risus a aliquam. Duis est augue, iaculis quis interdum eget, tempor accumsan quam. Vivamus vel lobortis augue,
          eu convallis lectus. Nam venenatis scelerisque maximus. Vivamus lobortis semper pharetra. Cras nisi dui, placerat congue
          nulla sed, suscipit dictum dui. Integer tristique quis ligula at dignissim. Vivamus pulvinar finibus tortor, vulputate
          placerat ante luctus ut. Nulla id euismod libero. Fusce in nunc tellus. Aliquam mattis sagittis tortor, id varius ex
          sodales eu. In mollis ultrices arcu vel consequat.</p>

        <p>Cras faucibus sem vitae erat fermentum tincidunt. Aenean id eleifend tellus. Fusce id scelerisque erat. Fusce pulvinar
          egestas sapien, et fermentum massa accumsan ultricies. Nullam laoreet, metus id hendrerit scelerisque, enim dui cursus
          nisi, in accumsan nibh erat vel dui. Sed aliquam hendrerit libero, vel laoreet urna tincidunt eget. Donec scelerisque
          quam ut fringilla blandit. Aenean lobortis commodo dui a eleifend. Etiam sed scelerisque purus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="social-actions">
        <a href="fb.com">Facebook</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.. using `position:fixed;` will fix your problem

Also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zv5fh0yk/

```css
#container
{
    max-width: 1000px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
}
#header
{
    float: left;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  
}
#header .inner {
    position: fixed;
    width:10%;
   
}

.inner li{list-style:none;}
#maincontent {
    width: 80%;
    float:right;
    padding-left:5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <header id="header">
        <div class="inner">
        <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Login</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="maincontent">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>


</div>
```